# Why is the Microsoft Translate API giving a 404?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-translator, azure-marketplace

I'm switching my translation code from Google Translate (deprecated) and the Microsoft SOAP API (also deprecated apparently to the shiny new Windows Azure Marketplace service.

But now I'm stuck, every call to the new service returns a 404. Here's my calling code:

```
var serviceRootUri = new
    Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/");
var accountKey = "(actual account key is here)";
TranslatorContainer tc = new TranslatorContainer(serviceRootUri);
tc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
var translationQuery = tc.Translate(InputText, OutputLanguage, InputLanguage);
var translationResults = translationQuery.Execute();
```

The last line is where the error occurs.

I pretty much followed this article:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Walkthrough-Translator-in-7e0be0f7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Translate()` call, assuming `OutputLanguage` and `InputLanguage` are of type `Language` or `DetectedLanguage`, change the parameters to `OutputLanguage.Code` and `InputLanguage.Code`. This is how I call it and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks David, they are actually strings I forgot to include... in this case, input="pt" and output="en".